# Android Main Activity is too slow

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 9 buttons on my main activity which navigates to particular fragment on clicking. but it is to heavy on main thread. how can  reduce the code size. can i use switch instead of defining 9 buttons 
here is the main activity code

MainActivity

```
package com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.AboutApp;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.AboutParty;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.Aims;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.CityList;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.Events;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.History;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.Martyrs;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.TwitterMain;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();





            final Button HistoryBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.historyBtn);
        HistoryBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new History()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button AimsBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aimsBtn);
        AimsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Aims()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button MembersBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.membersBtn);
        MembersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new CityList()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button PhotoBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.martyrsBtn);
        PhotoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Martyrs()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button TweetBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tweetsBtn);
        TweetBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new TwitterMain()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button AboutParty = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutParty);
        AboutParty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new AboutParty()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eventsBtn);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Events()).commit();

            }
        });

        final Button AboutApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutApp);
        AboutApp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Perform action on click

                mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new AboutApp()).commit();

            }
        });

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(myIntent);

}

}
```

Comment: Do you have any large images?

Comment: yes you can use switch better one. But you have less numbers of lines of code then why its slow. Is there any images in layout like how Knossos asked.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be the reason for that much delay. And to be honest, your onBackPressed method is doing something you definitely shouldn't do.

Comment: no i am not using images

Comment: Is your application slow at first start or it get's slower with time?

Comment: Is this your launch activity

Comment: Try to use Butterknife, it will help you tons with reducing the code. As far as I can see the code is normal, have you updated your emulator or phone to the latest version?

Comment: Use switch statement for on click method, but i don't see how this would improve your code for activity to be faster. Do you use emulator or real device for testing?

Comment: i am using Emulator and real device . it is slow on both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why your application might be getting slower is the way you treat the onBackPressed() event. Every time you hit the back press button anywhere in the app you are creating a new MainActivity, but you never finish the previous one and since that's your MainActivity you are pretty much recreating your whole application on every back press.

Comment: then how to handle onBackPressed() event in proper way. if i remove this then on back press application will exit instead of navigating back ?

Comment: getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

Comment: You are not doing any navigation at all.. You should treat your onBackPress with the fragment transition you desire. If you do not know how to do it there plenty of documentation in the web. For an easy hack, just call finish(); after startActivity();

Comment: @Shahzaib Idrees Baluch Like this :FragmentTransaction tx = fragmentManager.beginTransation();
tx.replace( R.id.fragment, new MyFragment() ).addToBackStack( "tag" ).commit();

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't seem to be something due to your activity class, but rather your XML files.

If anything, I would recommend creating an activity for each fragment an put them on it, just for tests. You can see how below.

**AboutAppActivity**

```
package com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.gowarbaam.baluchistannationalparty.Fragments.AboutApp;

public class AboutAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.containerView, new AboutApp())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

And on your **MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // This is not for performance, just DRY
    private View.OnClickListener btnOnClickListener(final Class activityClass) {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), activityClass);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        (...)
        final Button AboutApp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutApp);
        AboutApp.setOnClickListener(this.btnOnClickListener(AboutAppActivity.class));
    }


}
```